# mariadb remote connection fail in centos

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7, my.cnf

I have visited many websites for remote connection of MariaDb.
I have executed the command as below to create user with password in sql.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root@(my server ip)' IDENTIFIED BY '(my password)'

And i've added one line below [mysqld] in the file of /etc/my.cnf.d

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Then restart MariaDb service as below

sudo systemctl restart mariadb

Everything runs good.
However when i access by below command, it runs failed.

mysql -u root -p -h (my server ip)

I've turn off my firewall in my server, and turn on the port 3306 in GCP server, and it can be expected, i must fail to connect in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use a TCP connection, I assume that you want to connect to a remote server, not to a server running on the same machine.

1. Make sure that you are able to connect physically to the database server, e.g. with `telnet server_ip:3306`.
2. Determine the IP address of the computer from which you want to connect to the server (= client_ip).
3. Add a user on the server:
   `GRANT ... TO root@client_ip`

If client and server are running on the same machine, the preferred way is to use a linux socket (user@localhost) which is way faster.

Comment: Your assumption is right, my purpose is run connection in remote side, but i just test it in the same machine. i assumed that the same machine may have fewer condition to be considered.